# ERROR : has no exported member 'Ng2Bs3ModalModule'

Tags: angular

I am transforming my project from Angular 4 to Angular 7 and I get this error

> ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts(13,9): error TS2305: Module 'c:\localpathtoproject' has no exported member 'Ng2Bs3ModalModule'.

Tried almost all the solutions on the internet. Can someone point me out why this error is generated?

```
import {Ng2Bs3ModalModule} from 'ng2-bs3-modal/ng2-bs3-modal';



@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    Ng2Bs3ModalModule
    ]
 })
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: have you check the documentation. https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-bs3-modal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
import { BsModalModule } from 'ng2-bs3-modal';
```

refer this documentation for further implementation

https://github.com/dougludlow/ng2-bs3-modal

Answer (score 1):

According to updated documentation, you should import ng2-bs3-modal like below

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BsModalModule } from 'ng2-bs3-modal';

@NgModule({
    imports: [ BsModalModule ]
    ...
})
export class MyAppModule { }
```

Hope this will help!